# Visibility scope project/module

Tags: java, c#, android, scope, jvm

I have two projects/modules linked in Android Studio. One of them acts as an Api/Core, and I need that certain classes can by accessible only from this module but accesibles from all its packages (so “default” in this case is useless).

But it seems that in Java it isn’t a modifier like internal (c#, swift). “Module” modifier was proposed for Java 7 but it wasn’t implemented.

So, is there any way to protect the classes of a module from the outside world without limiting their scope to the current package?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure in the case of Android, but in standard Java, the answer would be no: the whole visibility is based on two parameters only:

- same package or not;
- inheriting the class or not.

When you import a library, you can access any non-private method (or actually overwrite one of the library classes) by putting your own class inside a package with the same name, so even if you restrict visibility to a package, you cannot prevent somebody from using the package-visible classes/methods.

**Edit**

Please note this answer applies until Java 8.

From Java 9, you can use a module system which provides much more control over what can be seen where. Once again, I don't know much about Android development (I tinkered with it back in 2010, but that has surely evolved since then), so I don't know if this is applicable in the context of this question.

Comment: So bad. This prevents to organizing your classes inside packages if you need to protect them from the outside world.

Comment: Yes indeed. What the outside world must not be able to use must be private. For all the rest, as I said, suffices to create the same package in your project, and you will be able to overwrite.

This has been useful to me actually. I am stuck with Spring 3.2.* and needed a Spring 4.1.* class for compatibility with another library, so I just copied the class I needed in the correct package, and the trick was done.

Now the question is to determine what you actually need to hide from the world, and what could be useful, but you are in the best position to know that.

Comment: It's things like this that make Java a micky mouse language. In C# you can use the "internal" access modifier.

Comment: As mentioned in [other answers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47218120/1734119), my answer is no longer true, as the module system fixes this issue. Once again, though, I'm not familiar with Android development and don't know if the modules can be used.

Answer (score 2):

There is no such an access modifier in jdk, but kotlin comes with `internal` modifier, which does precisely what you want: the class becomes public within the module, but is not accessible outside of the module.

For detailed explanation of differences between modifiers in Java and Kotlin refer to Fragmented podcast's [episode #101](http://fragmentedpodcast.com/episodes/101/) - *"Learning Kotlin – visibility modifiers, internal modifier, modules"*, as well as the [official docs](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/visibility-modifiers.html).

Answer (score 2):

Not until Java 9. The Java 9 module system solves this exact problem. Another answer mentions Kotlin `internal` scope, but a) the OP didn’t ask for a Kotlin solution, and b) I’ve found the Kotlin `internal` scope not playing well with IntelliJ, which is ironical considering that JetBrains created both.

Answer (score 0):

In the [Android annotations lib](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/annotation) there's one annotation that might help which is named [RestrictTo](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/annotations#libraries), though it's not going to hide your method, at least it will make Android Studio complain if somebody tries to use it elsewhere outside of your module.

It's worth noticing that, from what I saw, Android Studio will complain if said method is called inside a Java class. Unfortunately, it seems like Kotlin doesn't complain if you do the same there, so this alternative doesn't seem to work across languages.